# Truncated Response with Camel HTTP

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have an HTTP producer that calls a remote HTTP Server. I need to read the response from the HTTP Server and convert it into json and do some further processing.  I am experiencing some challenges dealing with big message bodies. I am not quite sure what the size threshold is. My code look

```
   <from uri="restlet:/foo"/>
   <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_URI">
            <simple>{{ConfigurableURL}}}</simple>
   </setHeader>
   <to uri="http://dymmyhost"/>
   <transform>
            <simple>${bodyAs('java.lang.String')}</simple>
   </transform>
   <transform>
        <groovy>org.json.simple.JSONValue.parse(request.body.trim())</groovy>
   </transform>
```

When the size is small enough, this works without problem. When it is big, the body gets truncated in the last transformation. And if I remove org.json.simple.JSONValue.parse from this last transformation, I end up with a error message such as:
      org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 2263; received: 2233

My digging suggested that there is a buffering issue going on. So, I added the parameter disableStreamCache=true to the URL. It did not help.

I also replaced the JSON parsing line with a proper Camel unmarshaller:

```
   <unmarshal ref="json"/>
```

Still it did not help. I get the exception: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Write the response from the remote HTTP server to a file before parsing it such as

```
<camel:to uri="file:data?fileName=download.htm" />
```

See http://camel.apache.org/file2.html for more options. As a nice side effect, this protects your server ram resources. When parsing the file, use a `Reader` instead of transfering the whole content into a `String`. Beside that, Camel provides powerful JSON support, see http://camel.apache.org/json.html.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Memory is no issue. On top of that , the performance implication in writing to file system would be quite huge. And yes, as I mentioned in the post, I also tried Camel-JSON, which is the unmarshaller you see above.

Comment: OK. But did you try to download the content to the file system? Is it possible that not the whole content is read from the server and that the problem is not the parsing but the downloading?

Comment: Indeed content is fully downloaded. I now realized from the logs that it is even fully processed by those two transforms. The issue is with the content length header it seems. Remote server has a gzip compressed content, resulting in size of 1045. Now, my route is accessible through RESTLET. However, the content has been decompressed; which resulted in content length of 2053. My HTTP client ends up reading 1045 characters as indicated in the header, which results in data truncation. I  am not sure though why it works with wrong content length if I remove those two transforms.

Comment: I guess this is a bug and you should open  an issue.  As a workaround you could download the content to a file as I recommended in my answer.